# Should POCO classes contain methods? If yes, how are they difference from domain objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, poco

Ok, so I have been trying to wrap by head around `domain driven development (DDD).`

I know that `POCO` classes are supposed to be simple and that they have no connection with entity framework. These are the classes will be mapped to entities when any database operation is needed.

I also know that in `DDD`, you have your classes with all of your business logic in it.

My question is, if I start putting logic and method inside my `POCO` classes, they will not stay simple anymore, but If I start creating and using my domain classes separately, I ll need to first map my domain object to `POCO` and then that `POCO` object to entity object and vice versa, which is getting hectic.

So should i go like: `Entities <--> POCO (Simple class) <--> Domain Object (All business logic)` or should I get rid of POCO classes and instead use domain classes only, since I am getting the work done including layer separation between BL and EF entities anyway.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, POCOs do not have any logic within them. They're mainly a holder class, consisting only of various fields and properties. Once you start adding logic into them, you start heading further down the road of domain driven design.

Many developers, like Martin Fowler rightfully argue that widespread use of POCOs lead to an [Anemic Domain Model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) defines as: "...the use of a software domain model where the domain objects contain little or no business logic". In my opinion, an anemic model while using EF is definitely a real risk if you do not take proactive measures to mitigate it.

That's not to say every system employing POCOs for entities is inherently doomed to produce an ADM. In fact, Jason Taylor has an [amazing talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lwCVE_XgqI&feature=youtu.be) on Clean Architecture, and his [Northwind Traders demo](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders) shows some great ways to potentially segment your application without sacrificing much clarity.

Modern Entity Framework Core lends itself very well to both design paradigms (POCOs and DDD), so there really is no "right" answer. I personally take a hybrid approach in most of my nontrivial use-cases. My entity models contain the hard and fast, universal domain rules for the entity; not to be confused with the domain logic. My domain layer contains most of the pertinent domain logic, or rather how various entities interact with each other. My application layer brings everything together, and it encompasses the actual logic responsible for making the program operate.

I do still have POCOs, but they're primarily used to transmit data to and from the client. I use them in conjunction with [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) and [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) to simplify the boilerplate code, but they're by no means necessary.

---

So when it comes to the POCO question, the answer is: "It depends".

Comment: POCOs may have behavior (you should be encouraged to add one).Martin Fowler explicitly says:
"Some technologies encourage it; such as J2EE's Entity Beans which is one of the reasons I prefer POJO domain models."
You probably thought about DTOs, not POCOs - they are very different beasts.